# Adobe AIR softKeyboardBehavior auto-pan

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have an Adobe AIR mobile app with many editable text fields, some of which get partially covered up by the soft keyboard when it opens. I am trying to take advantage of the "pan" softKeyboardBehavior, which causes the screen to automatically pan so the text is above the keyboard.

However, this always scrolls so that the line of text containing the cursor is immediately above the keyboard. In other words, if I have a 7-line textfield and the user taps the top line, the other 6 lines will be covered by the keyboard, making editing the text nearly impossible.

Is there any way to adjust how AIR positions the text relative to the keyboard when softKeyboardBehavior is set to "pan"?

Answer (score 0):

Almost immediately after I posted this, I thought about a decent workaround:

```
private function onSoftKeyboardActivate(event:SoftKeyboardEvent):void {
    textField.setSelection(textField.text.length, textField.text.length); 
}
```

This forces the cursor to the end of the text that's already in the textfield, which will scroll the textfield higher. If the number of lines of text is shorter than the length of the textfield, adding new text from the bottom will scroll the screen to make more of the textfield visible.